# Getting Access Denied for S3 when using GitHub Actions but not for Terminal

Tags: github, amazon-s3, github-actions, aws-cli

I am able to access my the bucket (SG) from my command line. However, when I run in GitHub actions, I get an access denied error. I have set the keys three times, so I know I am not using the wrong keys, and I know I have the correct permissions because it works in the terminal.

Some notes: The SG bucket is in a different region than mine. Also the SG bucket originally had a different endpoint. I need to ensure that it is pointing to the correct endpoints (https://s3.amazonaws.com). Currently I have the endpoint as a variable but do not set it.

Is there something wrong with my workflow YAML?

```
jobs: 
  Sync:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      SG_S3_ENDPOINT: https://s3.amazonaws.com
      SG2_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.SG2_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      SG2_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.SG2_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_REGION_NAME: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION_NAME }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: install dependencies ...
        run: |
          pip3 install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Sync Weekly Patterns
        run: |
          aws configure set aws_access_key_id $SG2_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $SG2_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          aws configure set region $AWS_REGION_NAME
          aws s3 sync s3://sg-places-outgoing/my_org/weekly/ s3://sg-my-org/weekly-patterns/
```

Comment: Why not just name the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` and avoid the need to setup local AWS configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem was that my environment variables were not named to the AWS-recognized values, even though I was setting them in aws configure.

```
  Sync:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      AWS_REGION_NAME: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION_NAME }}
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.SG_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.SG_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_S3_ENDPOINT: https://s3.amazonaws.com

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: install dependencies ...
        run: |
          pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Sync Weekly Patterns
        run: |
          
          aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          aws configure set region $AWS_REGION_NAME
          aws s3 sync s3://safegraph-places-outgoing/nyc_gov/weekly/ s3://safegraph-post-rdp/weekly-patterns/
```